# GraphQL Documentation Explorer not loading my schema

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

[image]I'm trying to set up a GraphQL Scheme through Express and when I load it with Graphiql it doesn't pick up the schema. When I run a query it says that I must provide a query string. My code is below. Can anyone spot anything I'm doing wrong? There are no errors in the console and the documentation explorer loads a spinning loading circle that never ends. Am I creating an infinite loop somehow?

here's the schema:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const _= require('lodash');

const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLSchema } = graphql;

//dummy data 

var books = [
    {name: 'book1', genre: 'genre1', id: '1'},
    {name: 'book2', genre: 'genre2', id: '2'},
    {name: 'book3', genre: 'genre3', id: '3'}
]

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        genre: {type: GraphQLString}
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        book: {
            type: BookType,
            args: {id: {type: GraphQLString}},
            resolve(parent, args) {
                //code to get data from db / other source
                return _.find(books, {id: args.id});
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
})
```

here's the server:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require("axios");
const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql')
const schema = require('./schema/schema')

// set up our middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("server/public"));
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
schema,
graphiql: true,
}));


   //loading on port 5000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("server running on: ", PORT);
});
```

Comment: I get the below error when I set graphiql to false

```{
"errors": [
{
"message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>.",
"locations": [
{
"line": 3,
"column": 1
}
]
}
]
}```

It's probably due to the fact that it's not picking up my string because it's not finding the scheme query. Why?? There are absolutely no errors in my node console.

Comment: I included a screenshot at the top of what happens when Graphiql loads. Again I'm getting no errors in my express server console. I'm at a total loss here

Answer (score 0):

bodyparser is incompatible with graphQL. In order to get this to work I had to remove the bodyparser middleware. This resolved it for anyone who might be following this thread.